# vscode interface operations do not work with ssh

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm using SSH to clone a project. I have added SSH-key to the SSH agent, but the git commands (fetch, pull, push,...) can only run on the git bash terminal used to add the SSH-key (it seems that each git bash is only used for 1 agent). ), leading to the fact that when I operate on the VS-code interface, it cannot run and reports a permission denied error as shown, it seems that VS-code's git command is running in another terminal. I wonder if anyone has ever encountered this situation and asked for a solution?

[image: the error image]

Comment: You're using Windows, right?

Comment: @GaëlJ yep, I am using window.